# Creating a pagination with db2

Tags: db2

I have read that DB2 doesn't support Limit and Offset. I also read that you have to uses ROW_NUMBER() and subqueries to get the desired result.
If this is an SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

where $offset is the offset and $rowsperpage is the amount of rows from database I want to be displayed on the page, what could be equivalent of this as a DB2 query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, depending on what platform of DB2 you are using, you didn't read the full story. [DB2 LUW has support for LIMIT and OFFSET, but you have to turn it on](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html?lang=en) (don't forget to restart DB2 after setting the flag). If you want to use DB2 with ROW_NUMBER() as you asked for, you could write the query as follows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn, 
               items.* 
          FROM items)
  WHERE rn BETWEEN computelowerboundaryhere AND computeupperboundaryhere;
```

There is also an [overview article describing the different ways of doing the LIMIT/OFFSET work in DB2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/limit_offset?lang=en).

Comment: I already tried turning it on and had already tried Limit Offset and it didn't work

Comment: Also @data_henrik I have the query almost working but it is displaying all the row numbers rather than the names of items

Comment: Instead of selecting all columns (*) you would need to pick just the columns you need (based on my generic example above).

Comment: I created a blog entry to show how to enable LIMIT and OFFSET in DB2 http://blog.4loeser.net/2015/12/limit-and-offset-in-db2-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

DB2 for I also has support for LIMIT and OFFSET as of the [latest technology refresh (7.1 TR11 and 7.2 TR3).](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/OFFSET%20and%20LIMIT)